# sharepoint 2013 script editor webpart works in snippet preview but not on site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Good Evening.  I am new to SharePoint 2013 and would like to put a basic web part on my site that is just a form to allow my users to do a google web search from our intranet page and the search results would open in a new tab or window.

I have the script inserted into a script editor web part,  when Im in the edit snippet window the preview below my code appears and works as tested,  but when I save the web part to my page when I try to search the page just refreshes and nothing is passed to google.

Here is the code in my script web part:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function search_google(){ 
window.open("http://www.google.com/search?q="+document.search.query.value); 
}
</script>
<form name="search">
<input type="text" name="query" value="">
<input type="submit" value="Search Google" onClick="search_google()">
</form>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is an old post, but to those that stumble across it: the reason for the page refreshing behaviour is because of the input type of "submit" on the "Search Google" input element. Submit always causes a page refresh in SharePoint (causing your onClick event handler to be ignored) UNLESS the page is in edit mode.

An input type of "button" should give you the desired behaviour in either page mode.

HTH, Bruce